# Finding out indices of maxima of sublists in python

Tags: python, list, max, sublist

I've a list `x` of n sublists. I want to make a `new_list` of length n containing the indices of maximum of each sublist. How can I pull this off?

For example:

```
x = [[1,4,2,3,5],[3,5,2,1,3],[5,2,1,4,3],[1,2,3,5,4],[4,1,5,2,3]]
```

(I've taken the maxima the same in each sublist for the ease of use)

And the output must hence be:

```
new_list = [4,1,0,3,2]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have access to `numpy` it is very easy:

```
In [9]: import numpy as np

In [10]: x = [[1,4,2,3,5],[3,5,2,1,3],[5,2,1,4,3],[1,2,3,5,4],[4,1,5,2,3]]

In [11]: a = np.array(x) # Assumes all sublists are of the same length

In [12]: np.argmax(a, axis=1)
Out[12]: array([4, 1, 0, 3, 2])
```

Answer (score 1):

Provided there are no duplicate items in each sublist, try the following:

```
new_list = [sub.index(max(sub)) for sub in x]
```

---

```
>>> x = [[1,4,2,3,5],[3,5,2,1,3],[5,2,1,4,3],[1,2,3,5,4],[4,1,5,2,3]]
>>> new_list = [sub.index(max(sub)) for sub in x]
>>> new_list
[4, 1, 0, 3, 2]
>>>
```

Comment: The list I'm handling has around 360 sublists and a total of around 80000 values. So, there could be duplicate values inside a sublist. Thank you much, anyway!

Comment: I'm using Python 2.7 and I'm getting an error.
AttributeError: 'numpy.float64' object has no attribute 'index'

Answer (score 1):

You can use lambda expression and map over l, to get the index of max element in `x`

```
l=[[1,4,2,3,5],[3,5,2,1,3],[5,2,1,4,3],[1,2,3,5,4],[4,1,5,2,3]]
print map(lambda x:x.index(max(x)),l)
```

Output:

```
[4, 1, 0, 3, 2]
```

If you are using numpy array,

```
>>> print map(lambda x:int(np.where(x==max(x))[0]),l)
[4, 1, 0, 3, 2]
```

Comment: Getting an error. I'm using Python 2.7. Could that be the reason?

Comment: Even I use python 2.7 Can you share the traceback. May be you can edit the question.

Comment: You never mentioned that you use numpy! Anyway, I've added the edits! Hope it helps!

Answer (score -1):

Make a new list by looping through and getting the max of each sublist:

Like so:

```
x = [[1,4,2,3,5],[3,5,2,1,3],[5,2,1,4,3],[1,2,3,5,4],[4,1,5,2,3]]

max_index = [i.index(max(i)) for i in x]
```

Comment: He wants the index, not the max value.